# How do I perform a network process in a kotlin coroutine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, networking, kotlin-coroutines

I am attempting to run the getByName method in my android app, but have found that doing so in the main activity is cause for concern. I know I need to use coroutines, or async, or threads. But I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm somewhat self-taught with the software so forgive any obvious errors.

'''

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val adr = getIpStr()
    val serverAdr = "http://" + adr + ":5000"
    val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    myWebView.loadUrl(serverAdr)
}

fun goToSettings(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private suspend fun getIpStr(): String? {
    delay(2000L)
    return getByName("raspberrypi").hostAddress
}
}
```

'''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting exception because you starts your coroutine on main thread.

To perform network request,you need to use background thread .For that you can use " launch " coroutine builder with IO dispatcher to start new coroutine on background thread.

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
val adr = getIpStr()
val serverAdr = "http://" + adr + ":5000"
//here switch to Main thread to Update your UI related task
withContext(Dispatchers.Main){     
myWebView.loadUrl(serverAdr)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to launch a coroutine using `lifecycleScope`:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val adr = getIpStr()
    val serverAdr = "http://" + adr + ":5000"
    val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    myWebView.loadUrl(serverAdr)
}
```

Alternatively, we can setup webview outside of `launch()`:

```kotlin
val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

lifecycleScope.launch {
    val adr = getIpStr()
    val serverAdr = "http://" + adr + ":5000"
    myWebView.loadUrl(serverAdr)
}
```

Comment: I tried this and my app still "keeps stopping" upon testing. Upon debugging I see I am still getting an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Apologies for the lack of specificity but do you have any idea what else could be occurring?

Comment: At which line does it happen? `getByName()`? `loadUrl()`? What is this `getByName()` function?